# lists functions- len ,cal

Tags: python, list, math

I'm thinking about making a small program that calculates a mathematical base.
I need to know the length of a list and I want to store in a variable its value!

I also want to add all the lists elements "they are numbers" and store there value all together in a variable.

Note: the list is really long, so I want an easy way. I know other long ways!

```
numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
x=len(numbers)
print(x)
```

---

Now how to all them all?

Comment: Can you clarify on *how to all them all*?

Comment: you mean using `sum()` function to add all elements inside the array?

Comment: sorry im meant to add them :")

Comment: jycr753 yes i meant :") but how ?

Comment: yes !! thank you very much :") sum() function worked !

Comment: Why do you offer `len` as an example of what you want, when it isn't at all what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `sum()`

```
numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
x=sum(numbers)
print(x)

>>prints 21
```